# get by role region with describedby not working for react testing library

Tags: react-testing-library, wai-aria

I am using region role for a section in my page.

It has describedby aria label which speak of what that section does.

I am writing unit test to make sure that section exists as shown in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-testing-library-demo-forked-xlw8bm?file=/src/__tests__/hello.js).

hello component:

```js
export default ({ name }) => <h1>Hello {name}!</h1>;
```

test:

```js
test("region described by hello region should exists in the dom", () => {
  const { getByText, getByRole } = render(<Hello name="Jill" />);
  expect(
    getByRole("region", { description: "hello region" })
  ).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Comment: To make helping you easier, I added the contents of your component hello.js in the question. Your component does not use any region, nor `aria-describedby`. It’s an `<h1>`, so it has `heading` role and no description. I don’t understand why your test should match that element?